# Error with PHP Websocket and Wamp Server

Tags: php, apache, websocket, wamp, phpwebsocket

I'm really new about this of Websockets, i'm trying to connect this websocket: [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) with WAMP server, first, in my httpd.conf I wrote listen 9300, and if i go to localhost:9300 it works right, but when I go to console and write:

```
 php -q C:\wamp\www\demos\server.php
```

I got this error:

[image: error]

Here's the code of server.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );
    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }

    if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
        $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
    else
        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
            if ( $id != $clientID )
                $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
}
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
$Server->wsStartServer('localhost', 9300);

?>
```

Thank you.

Oh, And my extensions:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

And also, the output of php -me

[image: PHP -me]

Comment: Probably you have not installed php5_socket extension.Try this http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php

Comment: i have the line like this:
extension=php_sockets.dll without the ;

Comment: type "php -me" in command line.Does it have "sockets" in output?

Comment: No, I don't have it D:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WAMP Server, if you are running from a command line you are using PHP CLI.

The PHP CLI uses a different php.ini file to that used when php runs in apache.

```
Edit c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini
```

and uncomment the php_sockets extension line and any other extensions you may need when running PHP CLI.

Comment: Ok, well with edit.exe I saw that i had the ; in php_sockets, i don't know why... but with notepad i had php_sockets without ; Whatever, thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Thanks for this - just wanted to add that in my particular configuration (UniServerZ) it was `php-cli.ini` I copied the line `extension=php_sockets.dll` from the php_development.ini file into `php-cli.ini` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install php_socket extension. http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php
This link have all information about it.

Answer (score 0):

i am running on my site and the hosting partner said you cant enable sockets on shared hosting u need to buy vps server hosting any solution.on local host it is working fine [property in dubai](http://propertyingulf.com/test/PaginaPHP.php)