# phpwebsocket - Undefined Function socket_create() - Have php_sockets enabled on Windows/WAMP

Tags: php, sockets, wamp, phpwebsocket

I checked out the PhpWebSockets project from here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/
```

It's in its own project on my localhost (Windows 7 64-bit) box, inside of a WAMP server.  I issue the following command in Windows Command Line to run the server.php file:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe C:\wamp\www\phpwebsocket\server.php
```

But it results in the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in C:\wamp\www\phpwebsocket\server.php on line 58
```

My WAMP instance DOES have the php_sockets extension enabled (since I saw [this similar question who had that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137823/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-socket-create)).

Anyone know what I could possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in another thread:

[Error with PHP Websocket and Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705630/error-with-php-websocket-and-wamp-server)

Turns out running the file on the command line means it uses a different php.ini file than the WAMP server does.  Seems stupid, but turned out php_sockets wasn't uncommented in that php.ini file, and removing it removed the error with it.